# Laravel: how to eager load a model that's two steps down?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have users which have many computers which belong to a certain computer_type (users->computers->computer_type).

I know that I can load both users and their computers with: `User::with("Computer")`

I would like to load all three. How can I do it in Laravel?

Comment: Laravel on Stackexchange http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel?referrer=VUgOWgZpXyO753uZWv1VMg2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To retrieve relationships that far down, you must say the child, then the child with it's child, and so on...

```
User::with(array('computer', 'computer.type'))->find(1);
```

User has_one Computer has_one type in this particular scenario.

Comment: In the above example you don't need to include computer. User::with('computer.type')->find(1); will autoload the computer relationship also. You don't want to wear out that keyboard do you?

Comment: And what if we just want the computer.type and not all the parents?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Appointment::with('kid.parent')->get()
```

if each kid has a appointment and each kid has a parent.